# RadNumericTextbox automatically change value when not in range

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have the following scenario -

This is my html element

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="percangeTextBox" Width="200px" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Enabled="true" Type="Percent" 
                MinValue="0" MaxValue="100">
                    <Clientevents onerror="HandleError" />
            </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

And I want to pop up my own message when a value not in ranged was entered. furthermore, I want to stop the annoying automatic value change after the invalid value was entered. So I have this function:

```
function HandleError(sender, eventArgs) {
                    var inputValue = eventArgs.get_inputText();
                    var minValue = sender.get_minValue();
                    var maxValue = sender.get_maxValue();
                    // out of range
                    if (eventArgs.get_reason() === 2) {
                        sender._invalid = true;
                        sender.updateCssClass();
                        var oWnd = $find("<%= RadWindowManager1.ClientID %>");
                        oWnd.set_title("Invalid parameter");
                        oWnd.radalert("Percentage must be between " + minValue + "-" + maxValue + ".");
                        eventArgs.set_cancel(true);
                    }
                }
```

When 100+ value is entered the text is changed to 100 and when 0- is entered the text changes to 0. How can I change this and keep original value? I tried changing the value but it changes back....

Comment: You can try using `OnValueChanged` and remove MinValue and MaxValue. [See it here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/input/client-side-programming/events/onvaluechanged)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to the HTML the following attribute: AllowOutOfRangeAutoCorrect="false". Another posibility is to add Clientevent for blur and change the value there manually.